# Owl carousel not loading slides because of autoheight

Tags: html, owl-carousel

*EDIT*

OK. So I found the problem. It is owl carousel's auto height function. If I remove it the images will load. However, I need that function because the images are all different sizes! What should I do?

Owl carousel seems not to be loading any of the slides. Not sure why because when I preview just locally it works perfectly fine.

Site: http://imdarrien.com/

[image]

[image]

Comment: check for error in `F12` developper console, tab "console". Tell us what are the errors.

Comment: Are your source images uploaded to your web server?

Comment: @TimTroiano Yup, if you click on next then you can see the images load. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

See the image below (from developer console)

[image]

As seen in the image above, you have an error in your Javascript.

Replace

```
$("#name").mouseover(function () {
    $('.slider').stop().animate({
        width: $('#name').width()
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('.slider')..stop()animate({
        width: 0
    }, 1000);
});
```

with

```
$("#name").mouseover(function () {
    $('.slider').stop().animate({
        width: $('#name').width()
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('.slider').stop()animate({
        width: 0
    }, 1000);
});
```

Notice the `..` in `$('.slider')..stop()animate({`.

**UPDATE**

I would recommend you to use the debugger tools to find and solve such simple script issues yourself. Use `f12` key to open the debugger tools in chrome.

Comment: I keep seeing the same errors. Maybe its something wrong with my computer then.

Comment: Try refreshing your page after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Yup I did that. I found out that it's the auto height function for owl carousel. If I remove it the images will load but I sort of need that function since a bunch of images are diff sizes. Not sure what to do. :(